# etckeeper pushing to github

Tags: git, etckeeper

I set up etckeeper and added the file `/etc/etckeeper/commit.d/60github-push` in order to push the commit to github.

```
[orschiro@thinkpad etc]$ sudo cat /etc/etckeeper/commit.d/60github-push 
#!/bin/sh 
set -e
if [ "$VCS" = git ] && [ -d .git ]; then   
  cd /etc/   
  git push origin master 
fi
```

However, pushing to github fails as etckeeper tries to push as root. Should the use of sudo not preserve my user account settings for git, including my ~/.ssh keys?

```
[orschiro@thinkpad etc]$ sudo etckeeper commit "test"
[master de5971c] test
 Author: orschiro <orschiro@thinkpad.(none)>
 3 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 rename etckeeper/{ => commit.d}/60github-push (100%)
 create mode 100644 test
no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Please make your `etckeeper` repository private.  Your `passwd` and `shadow` files are currently world readable.  There are usually lots of other sensitive files in `/etc/` such as SSL keys.  You should now change **all** the current secrets in there, including your password and the root password, everywhere you have used them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To preserve the current ssh keys for when you're in root, use `sudo -E`.
That way there's no need to add anything to the root ssh config

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has an issue with git still trying to use id_rsa instead of the key specified in /root/.ssh/config, here's my fix for it.

The following are my test configuration files before fixing them:

/root/.ssh/config:

```
Host bitbucket
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/bitbucket.pub
```

[repo]/.git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:trae32566/test.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

There are two problems with this:

1. SSH seems to require you to use the "Host" variable in place of [user]@[address|domain]
2. The configuration file seems to need the **private** key.

To fix the first problem I edited line 7 in [repo]/.git/config from:

```
url = git@bitbucket.org:trae32566/test.git
```

to:

```
url = bitbucket:trae32566/test.git
```

To fix the second problem I edited line 4 in /root/.ssh/config from:

```
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/bitbucket.pub
```

to:

```
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/bitbucket
```

source: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is specify a key to use for one repo and set it as a remote in your git repository.

Meaning you can put this in root's `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gitupstream
        HostName example.org
        User git
        IdentityFile /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Assuming you `git remote add gitupstream git@example.org:/myrepo` in this case then do `git push origin gitupstream`.

Comment: Thanks. Pushing to Github is working now. However, the author being displayed is wrong. It shows `Author: orschiro <orschiro@thinkpad.(none)>` which is different to what `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email` show.

Comment: You'll need to run that command as root too.

Comment: This did not fix it. I had to uncomment lines 43 to 53 in `etckeeper/commit.d/50vcs-commit` which export `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and so one and thus overwrite my global setting.

Comment: Yeah, it won't fix it if you don't do it properly. It's a set up I run and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

sudo will not preserve your  ~/.ssh keys. This is due to the fact that you are now root running that command. So it's going to look for root's ssh keys. So you'd have to create a key for root and add that to your github user.